# Why is my array returning the commas when I use slice()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do this coding challenge that takes a list and an index and returns the values in increments of the index. for example...

```
combo([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) ➞ [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

when I try to grab the values it also grabs the commas and messes up the code. It's currently returning `1,23,4` and so on.

```js
let newList = [];

function nCombo(list, index) {
  let newIndex = 0 + index;
  for (i = 0; list.length >= i; i += index) {
    newList.join(list.slice(i, newIndex));
    console.log(`slice = ${list.slice(i,newIndex)}`)
    console.log(newList);
    newIndex += index;
  }
  console.log(newList);
}

nCombo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2)
```

I tried to use join before I was using newList += list.slice(i , newIndex);

I don't know why it's doing this

Comment: newlist.join(',') will combine your existing array into a string with the comma as the joiner. What you have put in above is the result of a slice of an array, and that will become the joiner.

Comment: Maybe you should read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on `array.join` to see what it really does

Comment: I think you're confusing `array.join()` with `array.push()`. The latter is how you add something to an array.

Comment: I think you meant `newList.push(...list.slice(i, newIndex));`  Using `first.push(...second)` to add the elements of the `second` array onto the end of the `first` array.  (modifies the `first` array!)   `first.push(...second)` is like `first.push(second[0], second[1], second[2] /*etc.*/)`

Answer (score 1):

This was my attempt at the coding challenge you suggested. I'm not sure if my for loops provide the correct functionality, but `.push()` is working just fine.

Hopefully this helps,

```js
function combo(arr, index) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (i > j || i - j > index) {
        result.push([arr[j], arr[i]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
const index = 2;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Example usage:
console.log(combo(arr, index));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach.

```js
function nCombo(list, size) {
    if (!size) return [[]];
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length - size + 1; i++) {
        result.push(...nCombo(list.slice(i + 1), size - 1).map(a => [list[i], ...a]));
    }
    return result;
}

nCombo([1, 2, 3, 4], 2).map(a => console.log(...a));
console.log('----------')
nCombo([1, 2, 3, 4], 3).map(a => console.log(...a));
```